# Android low resolution (ldpi) icons & Icon Set Generator

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, icons, generator

I just noticed that when I create an icon out from my svg sources for the different diplay resolutions [ldpi-xhdpi] with the 'Android Icon Set Generator' using the Android Plugin for Eclipse (v21.1.0), lets take an Action Bar Icon as an example, the Generator stopped producing the ldpi icons.

I know the Generator produced those ldpi icons in the past and previous versions of the Android plugin. The new version now only creates mdpi-xhdpi versions and so does the Asset Studio you find online.
Now the ldpi version needs to scaled down manually, which I find inconvenient...

The [Icon Design Guideline](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) still mentiones the ldpi resolution, though...

Anyone knows if there's a new guidline to stop bundling ldpi icons with your apps? Or maybe there are no new Android devices with ldpi screens produced, which makes the ldpi resolution deprecated?

I'd be happy if someone had some info on this matter...

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why Google (via the ADT plugin) has stopped creating Icon Sets for `ldpi`. That being said, even the [Android Assest Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) has stopped creating icons for `ldpi`.

However, there are still quite a handful of devices which may support `ldpi`. Android, however, (*in my experience*) does a good job of scaling down resources from the `mdpi` set. Scaling up *might be* a problem. scaling down, not so much.

Personally speaking, since I have almost exclusively used the Android Asset Studio for generating the resources for me, and considering that they too don't provide for `ldpi` anymore, I typically create the Launcher Icon manually and have stopped using the `drawable-ldpi` folder for other assets within the app. And I have never faced a problem. But I suspect, this really is matter of choice, and hence, quite subjective. I have not seen any adverse effect of not using it but someone might just have.

If you do choose to create `ldpi` assets, the ratio is: [**3:4:6:8**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) with 3 being for `ldpi` going up till `xhpdi`. Going forward, the `ldpi` assets will need to be created manually.

> Anyone knows if there's a new guidline to stop bundling ldpi icons
>   with your apps? Or maybe there are no new Android devices with ldpi
>   screens produced, which makes the ldpi resolution deprecated?

There is no saying if the `ldpi` bucket will be deprecated and if yes, when. But there is a list of devices according to their pixel density bucket here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/. Not a big list, but the author of that post did make an effort. There is another one here: https://github.com/mataanin/android-devices/blob/master/phones%20ui%20-%20specs.csv. But I suspect, considering the deluge of devices, it would be humanly impossible to list them all.

There is also this list on [Wikipedia: List of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density) and the [Android Device Gallery](http://www.android.com/devices/).

Comment: Thanks to your extensive answer IceMan!

I think I'll do the same thing you suggest: Getting rid of all the icons in the ldpi-drawable folders in my projects only putting the launcher icon in there.
In one case that will make one of my apps I published in the Play Store approx 250KB smaller (assuming no new features) 
That's basically why I raised this question: if I could squeeze those extra KBs ;)
 
So far you've confirmed my speculation that google is gradually deprecating the ldpi density. 
Don't think there are many new devices running Android >= 4.x which have a ldpi screen.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that 9.8% of the market is running a small, ldpi device, regardless of the operating system.

Thank you iceman, I was able to resolve this issue by deleting my iconset in the drawable ldpi folder.  (I only have 1 icon set).